# depcheck and npm-check not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dependency-management

I'm trying to check a Node project for missing or unnecessary dependencies, so I've tried `depcheck` and `npm-check`, but they both fail in the same way, claiming all five dependencies are unnecessary when in fact they are all used, and as far as I can see, they are used in the normal way; `package.json` `bin` points to `ayane.js` which contains `require` directives for the dependencies. I tried specifying `--ignore-bin-package=false` to `depcheck`, but that made no difference. The project https://github.com/russellw/ayane is pretty small and simple, and doesn't do anything weird.

What am I missing? Both the programs in question are quite widely used; are there known problems with them?

Comment: could you show any error message? and to your question, yes it's common that npm fails.

Comment: @KingReload No error message per se, just the normal message saying all five dependencies were unused. Common that npm fails - can you expand on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, `depcheck` seems to not appreciate the `return` statement outside of a function.
If you run `depcheck --json`, you can see `depcheck` considers `ayane.js` as an invalidFiles:

> "invalidFiles":{"ayane/ayane.js":"SyntaxError: 'return' outside of function (62:1) ...

I'm not an expert on that and I don't often use `return` outside of a function so I am not sure if it is bad practice or not, especially in this case (and still remain curious about that).

For more information, here's the MDN error reference: [SyntaxError: return not in function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Bad_return_or_yield)

You can try to replace this line in the source code of the project (to `console.log('exit')` for example) and try to relaunch `depcheck`: you'll get no more "Unused dependencies" warning but a "get-stdin Missing dependencies", and it's right.

```
// ayane.js l.61
if (!commander.lang && !commander.args.length && tty.isatty(process.stdin.fd))
    return
```

If you want, you [can open an issue as a false alert in the depcheck repository](https://github.com/depcheck/depcheck#false-alert).

Comment: That's not happening for me. `depcheck --json` gives a record starting with `{"dependencies"...`. Maybe `return` outside a function is a recently added feature. Try upgrading your version of `depcheck`?

Comment: `depcheck --version` 0.6.7 Please look carefully the output of `depcheck --json`. There is an _invalidFiles_ entry at some point. It is not a "feature", it's a bug in ayane.js who made _depcheck_ not work correctly, and not check dependencies in an invalid file. Did you try what I suggest (replacing the return statement) ?

Comment: You're right, there was an invalid files indicator in the middle of that record, and when I take out the global return, it now works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Else you could maybe try the following steps:

1. `npm install dependency-check -g`
2. `dependency-check <package.json file or module folder path>`

Example: `dependency-check ./package.json`

You could check the following site for more info about it: [dependecy-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dependency-check)

If it doesn't work, check for any path problems. Might be the case if it still doesn't work and doesn't show the message: `Success! All dependencies used in the code are listed in package.json`

If you're not sure if everything has been installed correctly, I would recommend a reinstall of the npm module. I made a reinstall solution for mac before: [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43489762/7707749)

Comment: Thanks! This does indeed do one half the job, checking for missing dependencies. I'm still hoping for a program that does the other half, checking for unnecessary dependencies.

Comment: No problem ✌ and maybe you don't have unnecessary dependencies? You could also do `npm prune` to unbuild modules that aren't listed in the `package.json`, and you could check `npm help prune`

Comment: Did you try `npm prune`? You could also use `npm install cleanup-dependencies` . To use this go to the directory you want to clean up and run the command `clean-deps`.

Comment: Thanks, `npm prune` does indeed look like the appropriate command for what it does, though what I'm looking for is something different.