# React-Native env: node: No such file or directory

Tags: xcode, react-native

I'm getting the following build error when compiling my react-native project in Xcode env: node: No such file or directory

Not sure whats causing it? 
Node v8.9.4
React-Native v0.50.4
NPM v5.6.0
And I'm using nvm

Comment: Got it working by following the following - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43465086/env-node-no-such-file-or-directory-in-mac

Answer (score 95):

if you are using nvm do

```
sudo ln -s "$(which node)" /usr/local/bin/node
```

this will link current nvm to your usr local and next time Xcode will find the correct node path and version

Comment: just to confirm this was the solution for me in July 2021 - xcode 12.5.1

Comment: This is a great solution. Just one thing to keep in mind: it will specifically set the version of Node that XCode knows about to the one you currently have activated. If you ever switch versions of node using NVM, you should re-run this command so that XCode is symlinked to that same version

Comment: This is the right answer, on xcode 13. Caused by xcode not being able to find node (nvm)

Comment: Right answer for me too! It's also written in the readme file =)

Comment: Late to the party but this doesn't work for me: I'm getting the following error:

ln: /user/local/bin/node: No such file or directory.

Anyone that can help me out?

Comment: This worked for me, Xcode 13.3.1 and react-native version 0.70.5.

Comment: This worked for me, Xcode 14.2 React Native 0.68.3

Comment: Works for me too. XCode version 14.2

Comment: @BrentLeComte, please confirm you have the required .xcode.env.local file without any typos. Then confirm your currently used version of Node matches what you specified in that file. Double-check for typos. Try replacing it's contents with this if all else fails: `export NODE_BINARY=$(command -v node)`

Comment: @JibreelKeddo thanks for the response! It was indeed something to do with Node but as it has been almost half a year I kinda forgot what it was.

Comment: Works for me too! react-native 0.72.3 and Xcode 14.3.1

Answer (score 4):

Here is one of the solutions for this error if you're using `nvm` and `sentry`: https://docs.sentry.io/clients/react-native/manual-setup/#using-node-with-nvm

Comment: Page not found. This is why it's always best to provide the solution directly in the comment, rather than relying solely on an external link.

Comment: Working link - https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/troubleshooting/#using-node-with-nvm-or-volta

Using node with nvm or Volta
Xcode has trouble locating the default node binary if you're using nvm or Volta. To troubleshoot this, add node binary path to the Bundle React Native code and images build phase like this:

```bash
export NODE_BINARY=path/to/your/node
# ... rest of the script
```

Or execute this `ln -s $(which node) /usr/local/bin/node` in your terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Xcode have some issues finding node from nvm, try this inside the script that throws the error:

```
# Setup nvm and set node
[ -z "$NVM_DIR" ] && export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"

if [[ -s "$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh" ]]; then
. "$HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh"
elif [[ -x "$(command -v brew)" && -s "$(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh" ]]; then
. "$(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh"
fi

[ -z "$NODE_BINARY" ] && export NODE_BINARY="node"

$NODE_BINARY ../node_modules/@sentry/cli/bin/sentry-cli upload-dsym
```

Comment: This solution worked for me running React Native >= 0.60 with sentry-react-native version 1.7.2. Navigate to Build Phases --> Bundle React Native code and images

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this was related to an old sentry configuration and the fact that I use nvm.

Following https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/manual-setup/manual-setup/

you should be able to execute `ln -s $(which node) /usr/local/bin/node` and get it fixed

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the top of the script that's failing (in Project -> build phases):

```
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used [documented here](https://blog.nigelsim.org/2022-12-09-nvm-node-from-xcode/), was to create a script at `/usr/local/bin/node` that calls nvm

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# Use the version of node specified in .nvmrc to run the supplied command

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && \. "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm

nvm_rc_version > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
HAS_NVM_RC=$?

if [[ "$HAS_NVM_RC" == "0" ]] ; then
        nvm run $*
else 
        nvm run default $*
fi
exit $?
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the presence of a file name `ios/.xcode.env.local` which might be taking precedence over your `ios/.xcode.env` file that typically sets the `NODE_BINARY` environment variable for building React Native projects:

```
export NODE_BINARY=$(command -v node)
```

In my case there was a `ios/.xcode.env.local` which was setting the `NODE_BINARY` using a temporary path under `/var/folders/dy/` - this could be seen from the Xcode build output.

I was using Xcode 15.0.1 to build a React Native 0.72.9 project. The `React-rncore` CocoaPods pod target was failing due to this (now invalid) path

The build output was showing

```
Node found at: /var/folders/dy/bbm86qs502g4h1qx3dhrpyk40000gn/T/yarn--1706023232853-0.9009324729880421/node
```

and then failing on the next line:

```
<project-path>/ios/Pods/../../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/../scripts/react_native_pods_utils/script_phases.sh: line 34: /var/folders/dy/bbm86qs502g4h1qx3dhrpyk40000gn/T/yarn--1706023232853-0.9009324729880421/node: No such file or directory
```

Comment: oddly the local env file exists and contains a single entry, NODE_BINARY, which points to the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

I read through all the other answers.

In my case everything was pointing to the right place.

This is .xcode.env.local :

```
export NODE_BINARY=/opt/local/bin/node
```

`env node` and `command -v node` were resolving properly in the terminal to `/opt/local/bin/node` which is valid yet the build still failed with `env: node: No such file or directory`

So I figured that `env` when called by xcode was not able to find node because the directory containing it was not it its `$PATH`.

So I added the following line at the end of `.xcode.env.local` and it worked:

```
export PATH=$PATH:`dirname $NODE_BINARY`
```