# installing react native - Command line interface (env: node: No such file or directory)

Tags: react-native, command-line-interface

While executing this command on terminal(Mac OS) for setup react native environment
**:~ npm install -g react-native-cli**
getting error **env: node: No such file or directory**

Comment: Which OS are you using ? Do you have node installed ?

Comment: You can find a solution here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43465086/env-node-no-such-file-or-directory-in-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43465086/env-node-no-such-file-or-directory-in-mac)

Comment: Using OS X......

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ubuntu try the command as

`sudo npm install -g react-native-cli`

and make sure **node** and n**strong text**pm was installed in your system.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have node installed on your system. Follow the instructions on [this link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

for MacOS

Install Homebrew

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Install Node

`brew install node`

Install watchman

`brew install watchman`

Finally install React Native CLI

`npm install -g react-native-cli`